# Why the meaning of "coordination devices" is quite abnormal

Tags: phrase-meaning

[Costola, 2021](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176521002986) said:

> Recently, the ‘‘meme stock’’ phenomenon has received considerable
> attention as social media were used as **coordination devices** to
> synchronize on buying signals that have significantly affected the
> price and trading volumes of certain stocks

Because I was not familiar to the phrase "coordination devices" so I did a Google search [here](https://www.w3.org/2008/07/pisa/Intro_Device%20Coordination.pdf)

> What is a coordinating device? Device coordination is broadly defined
> as a mechanism to eliminate or at least mitigate the interdependencies
> among devices to achieve a mutually agreed goal service by means of
> facilitating purposeful communication between devices

The explanation looks good to me until "**a mechanism to eliminate or at least mitigate the interdependencies among devices to achieve a mutually agreed goal**". I am not sure ELL is the right place to ask but it is strange regarding logic here to me that why we need to eliminate the interdependencies to achieve a mutually agreed goal? I thought that we should enhance the interdependencies to achieve the mutual agreement easier?

Comment: Your first example uses ***device*** much more figuratively (cf [literary device](https://literaryterms.net/literary-device/)), to mean *any* kind of ***mechanism / method / technique***, whereas the second example is much more literally referring to ***gadgets / machines / hardware***. Other than that, the two "context-sensitive" meanings are more or less the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the two sources are using "device" in different ways. See the first two definitions [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/device).

The Costola quote is using the first definition, in which a *device* is simply a "thing with a purpose." It then modifies *device* with *coordination*: it's saying that social media (note, the word "media" is plural) were used to coordinate trading of stocks.

The W3 document is using Cambridge's second definition for *device*, "a machine, for example a phone or computer, that can be used to connect to the internet." It also creates a very specific and narrow definition of its own for the phrase "coordination device," a definition that isn't relevant outside of the information-technology context.